# adb uiautomator can't access XML elements on WebView apps

Tags: android, xml, adb

I'm using this command for getting UI Elements/XML of Apps based on WebView. In this case, I'm using the UPS app from the Play Store. This app is WebView based. Right now my device its using
"Android System WebView (Chromium) 99.0" i also tried "Bromite System WebView" but without success.
Sometimes, the dump actually work and I get the UI Elements and the xml file, but in some cases the xml file is empty, giving me nothing.

Command:

```
adb shell uiautomator dump /sdcard/file.xml
```